# Custom animation by overriding transformPage(View view, float position) method of PageTransformer class of View Pager

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

I want my view pager animation like below image from left and right side both.
I have 3 pages. the middle one should not move. when I will move left or right only left or the right page will scroll with little fade in middle screen.

I am making animation with overriding the transformPage(View view, float position) method of PageTransformer class in view pager

[image]
[image]

```
 private final PageTransformer mPageTransformer2 = new PageTransformer() {
    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        Log.d("CalViewPager", "transformPage: " + position );

        if (position < 0.0f ) {
            // Pin the left page to the left side.
            view.setTranslationX(getWidth() * -position);
            view.setAlpha(Math.max(1.0f - position, 0.0f));
        } else{
            // Use the default slide transition when moving to the next page.
            view.setTranslationX(0.0f);
            view.setAlpha(1.0f);
        }


    };
```

Above code works fine from right side and i am trying to do in left side also. So, i try to understand the position value of transform(View view, float position) method. but i am unable to figure out how it changes with view?

What i found
if i swap right side each position value increase by 1 and if in left side then it get decrease by 1. but how would I know which view has which position value?

Note: - please comment if you didn't get my question or need more explanation

Answer (score 0):

You must use the following code :

```
public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
       final float normalizedposition = Math.abs(Math.abs(position) - 1);
       page.setScaleX(normalizedposition / 2 + 0.5f);
       page.setScaleY(normalizedposition / 2 + 0.5f);
```

}

For example, visit this website [example of cardpager yazdani](http://andraskindler.com/blog/2013/create-viewpager-transitions-a-pagertransformer-example/)